# How to get path of a file which is in IsolatedStorage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, isolatedstorage

I want to set an image which is stored in `IsolatedStorage` as background image of a tile.

we create tiles this way:

```
StandardTileData tile = new StandardTileData();
```

Now `tile.BackgroundImage` accepts a `Uri`. what is full path of an image which is in `/MyFolder/MyFile.png` in IsolatedStorage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tile.BackgroundImage = new Uri("isostore:/MyFolder/MyFile.png", UriKind.Absolute);
```

Here's more information about data in WP8: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: thanks for help, but it says `An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred `. seems files in IsolatedStorage is not supported for tiles backgrounds

Comment: I think the image needs to be located in: `/Shared/ShellContent `

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```html
  StorageFolder folder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
                 
                var path = folder.Path;
```